# Python scrape with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I'm trying to retrieve data from this webpage:

http://brmr.biz/product/2716370/name/000300020_30_2_DOORSLAG

I'm using Python 2.7.10 and the BeautifulSoup Library.

This is my code:

```
from BeautifulSoup
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url="http://brmr.biz/product/2716370/name/000300020_30_2_DOORSLAG"

page=urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(page)

data = soup.findAll("span", {"class":"price_bigger"})

print data`
```

I'm trying to get the 5,90 value (price excl tax)? My code gets me the result "request price"

I tried "stalling" the code with time.sleep(1) to "load" the data, but this does not work.

Thnx for helping me

Comment: Wrap code inside three backticks, \`\`\````code here```\`\`\`. And it's "Thanks"!

Comment: You may need to retrieve the price by requesting it directly. The price is retrieved by the page through a POST to "http://be.brammer.biz/products/show-price". The form data gives a product identifier. The result is a JSON message with the price information.

Comment: It seems that the provider dosn't want to be scraped. :) - Maybe, you have to find more sophisticated solutions like http://koaning.github.io/html/scapingdynamicwebsites.html. I'm not posting it as an answer, because I'm not sure if you can't get the price still without changing too much in your code. joshuanapoli gives a good hint for that, imo.

Comment: I will look at selenium. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out in comments, the `price` is loaded dynamically with an additional POST request that you need to simulate in your code.

Here I'm using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to maintain a web-scraping session and [`beautifulsoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://be.brammer.biz/product/2716370/name/000300020_30_2_DOORSLAG"
price_url = "http://be.brammer.biz/products/show-price"

with requests.Session() as session:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).content)

    # extract the product code - used in the POST request
    product_code = soup.find(id="localitemid")["value"]

    response = session.post(price_url, data={
        "ids[0][]": product_code
    }, headers={
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    })

    print(response.json())
```

Prints an object containing a price inside:

```
{u'bd792fcb87': [{u'delivery_time': u'6-10', u'quantity_min': 1, u'hash': u'bd792fcb87', u'qty_order_interval': 1, u'price': u'5,90\xa0\u20ac', u'tax': 0.21, u'delivery_desc': u'Aanvraag / Demande / Anfrage', u'price_unlocalized': 5.9, u'localitemid': u'2000010600', u'currency': u'\u20ac', u'quantity_available': 0, u'delivery_time_max': 10, u'quantity_interval': 1, u'price_quantity': 1, u'price_vat': u'7,14\xa0\u20ac'}]}
```

Comment: This really helps! Thank you.